# How to connect Golang Lambda function with Redis Elasticache AWS

Tags: linux, api, go, aws-lambda, redis

I'm new with golang.

I've been looking [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/GettingStarted.ConnectToCacheNode.html) of lambda-golang-AWS and still had this timeout in when invoking the function.

I've been configuring:

1. Elasticache cluster (1 primary node),
2. VPC (one same VPC for redis and lambda),
3. Security groups,
4. Subnets,
5. Inbound and outbound,
6. role

I have this primary Redis endpoint `xxxxxx`

I just need an example.

So, my questions are:

1. Can we connect Redis in Linux without an EC2 instance? Possibly try it with RDM.
2. How do we put AWS redis's endpoint in the main function? (do we only need the endpoint? or else)
3. Is it possible to connect to Redis Elasticache with only endpoint (without AUTH)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can leverage lambda execution roles. Have you [tried this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-elasticache-tutorial.html)?

Comment: @nitrin0 the execution role is just part of deploying a Lambda function in a VPC, that alone doesn't do anything to give it special Redis access.

Comment: @MarkB i was under the impression it was enough (meaning: allow lambdas to access resources in the VPC, namelly Elastic Cache) to do so but i'll review my setup in a older project. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: thank you @nitrin0.
from the link, I was adding the roles but still got the timeout. 

I was wondering... is that means, I need to set up NAT gateway to use the list of external modules in go.mod? does it matter with connecting to Redis cluster?

Comment: @rulisastra I'm not sure what you mean by external modules. You have to include all modules in your Lambda function's deployment package. You can't download and install things in the Lambda function after it starts running, because the filesystem is read-only.

Comment: [Tutorial: Configuring a Lambda function to access Amazon ElastiCache in an Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-elasticache-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we connect Redis in Linux without an EC2 instance?

Yes, of course, why would an EC2 instance be an additional requirement? You just need to include a Redis client library in your Lambda function's deployment artifact, and configure the Elasticache cluster to allow inbound traffic from the security group assigned to the Lambda function.

> How do we put AWS redis's endpoint in the main function? (do we only
> need the endpoint? or else)

I would configure the endpoint as one of the Lambda function's environment variables.

> Is it possible to connect to Redis Elasticache with only endpoint
> (without AUTH)?

If you don't enable AUTH on Elasticache, then you can connect without AUTH. AUTH is an optional configuration setting.

Comment: thank you for the confirmation! this helps a lot to limit my options.
I've included it in env of course, but still got the timeout.
do you have any doc about implementing the config on golang?

Comment: To answer your question, the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/GettingStarted.AuthorizeAccess.html) say this: "All ElastiCache clusters are designed to be accessed from an Amazon EC2 instance."